# FindPanel DevExpress Component Too Slow

Tags: c#, devexpress

I need a search panel similar to the findpanel in devexpress. FindPanel is a bit slow: it searches all the visible columns and removes the not-fitting-the-description rows from the xtragrid. If you know a way to override these unwanted behaviors or another component that does the same job without the previous behaviors please do share. If not...

I need to create a panel, with one textedit, and two simplebuttons in it. And since I am going to use this same component with different xtragrids over and over again, I need to make it a standalone component, and be able to point towards the xtragrid from the properties window. As if its a standard component.

So how do I do that ? If you have an entire example project it would be perfect, but if not, I am just looking for some pointers.

Thank you...

Comment: AutofilterRow is used for searching on individual columns. You can use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property to specify a list of columns for search by: [ColumnViewOptionsFind.FindFilterColumns Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnViewOptionsFind_FindFilterColumnstopic)

You also can create a standalone user control with the public GridView property. This property allows you to select GridView instances in the designer. To apply the search expression programmatically, use the [ColumnView.ApplyFindFilter Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ApplyFindFiltertopic)